# FUELCMS(codeigniter) htaccess: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to use fuelcms in my arch linux lamp server. But I cant make htaccess to work. My home folder is  ytsejam/fuel_cms/..

This is my .htaccess file  :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

<Files .*>
    Order deny, allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow asset folders through
RewriteRule ^(fuel/modules/(.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+|\.git.+) - [F,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [L]
</IfModule>
 Options -Indexes
```

/var/log/httpd/error_logs show that

```
/home/ytsejam/public_html/fuel_cms/.htaccess: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have just inserted additional space after the comma

`"deny, allow"` must be `"deny,allow"`

Comment: Thanks! I wasted 30 minute to figure why it doesn't work